# Adding in a for loop without Sum

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sum, addition

I think i'm over thinking this and need a new point of view.

I want to do this;

```
    SX=(cell2mat(X(:,1))+cell2mat(X(:,2))+cell2mat(X(:,3))+cell2mat(X(:,4)))/4
```

But in a for loop because in the end it will be a lot more then 4 different data sets.
So far my loop looks like this.

```
 for i=1:turns
    Sx=cell2mat(X(:,i))
       %insert a form off addition?
 end
```

The problem is I can't use sum as it's a 18 x 100 matrix and needs to stay that way. It works when I do the top coding, but that's not practical for n>50.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SX = mean(cell2mat(reshape(X, [1 1 3])), 3)
```

No loop required, and works for any 'n'.

**EDIT -** New solution based on information on comments:

```
SX = mean(cell2mat(reshape(X, [size(X,1), 1, size(X,2)])), 3)
```

Comment: When I attempt this solution an error in the reshape function pops up, I don't really understand how the (X,[1 1 3]) and the cell2mat, 3 work. Could you please explain? I may be able to see how I can alter it to work. Thank you for answering though :)

Comment: Could you provide more info about your `X` variable?

Comment: X is a 18 * 4 cell, with each cell = 1 * 100 arrays, so when cell2mat is used it becomes a 18*400 matrix...

Comment: I've edited my post with a new solution. Please see if it does what you expect now.

Comment: Yep! Much faster then the reshaping crazyness I have, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
SX = mean(cell2mat(X),2)
```

Or this?

```
[M,N] = size(X{1});
SX = mean(reshape(cell2mat(horzcat(X{:})),M,N,[]),3)
```

It really depends on how is your data setup in `X`.

Comment: The first one does the same as sum, and causes my 18*100*4 cell to equal a 18*1 array. However I want to keep it a matrix of 18*100 and just average the 4 cell's. The second solution doesn't work, can you explain the logic behind it? I might be able to alter it to fit, but I've never used horzcat or [M,N]=size(X{1}) before (btw that produces a M=1 and N=100). It causes an 'error' in the cell2mat function. Thank you for answering though :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using reshape, it is a bit longer in coding compared to the other solutions, but it works for any amount of n, and allows it to stay it's 18*100 in the end :)

```
  xx=cell2mat(X');
  xxx=xx';
  sx=mean(xxx,2);
  SX=reshape(sx,100,18);
  Mean_X=SX'
```

I ended up just expanding it to a 1800*4 matrix, transposing it sporadically to get my 1*100 = 100*1, then finding the mean for each row of n, the reshaping it back to a 18*100. And it works for a n=5 or n=60 or n=150 so yay. Thank you though to the others, I wouldn't of thought of reshaping it and fixated on for loops!